# How to generate XML from Java POJO using VTD XML

Tags: pojo, jaas, vtd-xml

I am not able to find any document/tutorial/example, hence, posting it.

Can someone help point to a document which shows how to convert a POJO to XML using `VTD-XML` library? I looked into their API doc, but didn't find anything there.

Comment: POJO to xml? that is the job of your xml binding frame work... what do you think?

Comment: I agree; but most frameworks provide both ways - binding and parsing. VTD-XML provides only one way. Perhaps that's what it is supposed to do. I wish it supports both parsing and binding; that way I would not be required to use multiple libraries. Anyways, I was also leaning towards the same conclusion and your answer assured me fully.